# I got this mistake when I run the code utilizing tesseract and the procedure will stop the checking

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I got this mistake when I run the code utilizing `tesseract` and the procedure will stop the checking it

`Uncaught (in guarantee) abort("trap!123"). Work with - s ASSERTIONS=1` for more data.

Comment: We need your code and the "more data" you get by following the hint